# Center the text widget inside transform scale in Flutter

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, rotation, widget, transform

How can we edit the children of this widget in a widget that we use transform scale?

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRXRI.png)

Code:

```
Transform.rotate(
              angle: math.pi / 4,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: const Color(0xff565758),
                child: const Text("Lorem ipsum"),
              ),
            ),
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utnaw.png)

Tried transform, transform.scale, FittedBox widgets. And the result is as in the picture above.

Solve:

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Transform.rotate(
              angle: math.pi / 4,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: const Color(0xff565758),
              ),
            ),
            const Positioned.fill(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("Lorem ipsum")))
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: pseudo structure: `Stack[Transform.rotate>Container, Text]`

Comment: Thak you so much @pskinin

Comment: your welcome, but actually you can also use this custom shape: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/StarBorder-class.html with `points: 4` and non zero `rotation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a stack to achieve this

```
Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Transform.rotate(
                    angle: math.pi / 4,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      color: const Color(0xff565758),
                      // child: const Text("Lorem ipsum"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text("Lorem ipsum"),
                ],
              ),
```